# How to initialize NSData Object with NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdata

In my iphone app, I have an NSMutableArray which i want to store into NSData.

I am not finding a way with which I can do so.

What should be done??

Please help and suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with the NSData object?

Comment: i need to export to file

Comment: Try NSArray's -writeToFile:atomically: method perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out NSPropertyListSerialization. That should let you convert the array to an NSData containing a property list. Note though that everything in the array has to support this (NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, etc... are all valid property list types).

Comment: Thanks!! Your suggestion for using  NSArray's writeToFile:atomically: method worked for me.